# Error when adding native prebuilt library to Android project

Tags: java, android, c++, gradle, android-ndk

Using a static prebuild library with `gradle 2.2.0` using `build.gradle` and `CMakeLists.txt`

I am currently trying to utilize [libusb](https://github.com/libusb/libusb) in my Android NDK project. I went ahead and compiled the library, and in the `android/libs/` directory exists the compiled libraries in their respective ABI directories. I copied the contents of the `android/libs/` directory into the libs directory of my android project and then followed the instructions found [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#create-cmake-script) (Subsection "Add other prebuilt libraries").

Pastebin links to my `build.gradle` and `CMakeLists.txt` are posted below.

In my `MainActivity.java`, I am loading my library in a similar way I load the native-lib:

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("lib-usb");
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }
```

And in my `src/main/cpp/rtl2832.h` file, I am including the `libusb.h` header like so:

```
#include "libusb/libusb.h"
```

My issue is that every time I run '`Make Project'` I run into the following error:

```
Error:(10, 10) fatal error: 'libusb/libusb.h' file not found
```

Since I do not have enough rep to post the links, the links to the build.gradle and CMakeLists.txt are below:

- [build.gradle](http://pastebin.com/csadLSZa)
- [CMakeLists.txt](http://pastebin.com/4dVPvDyc)

Am I including the file incorrectly or am I importing the library incorrectly or something entirely different? Thank you for your help in advance.